# I can't import prophet from fbprophet

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, facebook-prophet

I think this is simple question but I can't find solution

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from fbprophet import prophet
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squre_error,mean_absolute_error
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

this is my code when I execute this I  got error

[image]

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-1-cca636903a85> in <module>
  3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  4 import seaborn as sns
  ----> 5 from fbprophet import prophet
  6 from sklearn.metrics import mean_squre_error,mean_absolute_error
  7 plt.style.use('ggplot')
  **ImportError: cannot import name 'prophet' from 'fbprophet' (C:\Users\senth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fbprophet\__init__.py)**
```

can anyone help me to solve the error..!!

Comment: `from fbprophet import Prophet` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have imported the model with the wrong capilization.
The correct import, according to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html#python-api) is:

```
from fbprophet import Prophet
```